# Trying to import package d3/d3.js in Angular dart.

Tags: d3.js, angular-dart

I have moved from Java to AngularDart for a project where I have to visualise some numbers and a threat level based on data.

I decided to try to do a pie/doughnut shape with pie slices showing data properties and the centre is to show the threat level as a coloured circle.

I found an old D3Dart package and used that for my first attempt. Works fine. I can build arc's including inner- and outer radius, start- and end-angle, etc.

Reading examples on how to build I was inspired to try and move to d3/d3.js, which has (I guess) a better interface to d3.js. I need to be able to better control how I display things f.ex. replace a node element in the DOM.

When tying to import the package with `import 'package:d3/d3.js' as d3;`
pub serve fails with the message:

```
> D:\apps\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat serve web --port=54969 Loading
> source assets... Loading angular, test/pub_serve and
> dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers... Serving SimplePie web on
> http://localhost:54969 [web] GET Served 2 assets. [web] GET styles.css
> => SimplePie|web/styles.css Build error: Transform BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'TemplatePlaceholderBuilder' on SimplePie|primary threw
> error: Error in <unknown source>: Illegal character '949'.
> 
> Error in <unknown source>: Illegal character '949'.
```

Last line is repeated many times.
What am I missing in my import

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: SimplePie
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
version: 0.0.1

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  color: any
  angular: ^4.0.0
  angular_components: ^0.8.0
  d3: ^0.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^1.0.0
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  test: ^0.12.0

transformers:
- angular:
    entry_points:
      - web/main.dart
      - test/**_test.dart
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Snippet of my dart code that fails when I add d3/d3.js:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math' as Math;
import 'package:d3/d3.js' as d3;

import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component (
    selector: "pie-chart",
    templateUrl: 'pie_chart.html',
    directives: const[CORE_DIRECTIVES, materialDirectives],
    providers: const[materialProviders]
)

class SimplePie implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("containerPieChart")
    List<num> pieSliceList;
    num numberOfSlices;
    Math.Random random = new Math.Random();
    final num MAX_PIE_SLICE_SIZE = 20;
    num totalPieSize;
    num width;
    num height;
    num radius;
    num strokeWidth;
    var progressText;

    void ngAfterViewInit() {
        setup();
        totalPieSize = 0;
        for (num i = 0 ; i < random.nextInt(10) ; i++ ) {
            var value = random.nextInt(MAX_PIE_SLICE_SIZE);
            pieSliceList.add(value);
            totalPieSize += value;
        }
        numberOfSlices = pieSliceList.length;
        progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
    }

    void setup () {
        this.width = 800;
        this.height = 800;
        this.strokeWidth = 3;
        this.radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 2 * strokeWidth;
    }
}
```

I use IntelliJ IDE (latest) and Dart version 1.24.3.

Comment: Package d3 is a collection of libraries so the import should have been `import 'package:d3/js/d3.dart' as d3`
Then it is just fine